# MP3 streaming on iOS

Tags: iphone, openal

I want to use OpenAL to play music in an iOS game. The music files are stored in mp3 format and I want to stream them using a buffer queue. I load audio data into the buffers using *AudioFileReadPacketData()*. However playing the buffers only gives me noise. It works perfectly for caf files, but not for mp3s. Did I miss some vital step in decoding the file?

Code I use to open the sound file:

```
- (void) openFile:(NSString*)fileName {
   NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
   CFURLRef url = (CFURLRef)[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[bundle pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"mp3"]] retain];
   AudioFileOpenURL(url, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &audioFile);
   AudioStreamBasicDescription theFormat;
   UInt32 formatSize = sizeof(theFormat);
   AudioFileGetProperty(audioFile, kAudioFilePropertyDataFormat, &formatSize, &theFormat);  
   freq = (ALsizei)theFormat.mSampleRate;
   CFRelease(url);
}
```

Code I use to fill in buffers:

```
- (void) loadOneChunkIntoBuffer:(ALuint)buffer {
    char data[STREAM_BUFFER_SIZE];
    UInt32 loadSize = STREAM_BUFFER_SIZE;
    AudioStreamPacketDescription packetDesc[STREAM_PACKETS];
    UInt32 numPackets = STREAM_PACKETS;
    AudioFileReadPacketData(audioFile, NO, &loadSize, packetDesc, packetsLoaded, &numPackets, data);
    alBufferData(buffer, AL_FORMAT_STEREO16, data, loadSize, freq);
    packetsLoaded += numPackets;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're reading bytes of MP3 data and treating them as PCM data.

<strike>You almost certainly want `AudioFileReadPacketData()`.</strike> **EDIT:** Except that still gives you MP3 data; it just gives it in packets and (possibly) parses packet headers.

If you don't require OpenAL, AVAudioPlayer is probably the better way to go (according to the [Multimedia Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html), there's also Audio Queue services if you want more control).

If you really need to use OpenAL, according to [TN2199](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/technotes/tn2008/tn2199.html) you'll need to convert it to PCM in the native byte order. See [oalTouch/Classes/MyOpenALSupport.c](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/oalTouch/Listings/Classes_MyOpenALSupport_c.html) for an example of using Extended Audio File Services to do this. Note that TN2199 says the format "must ... not use hardware decompression" — according to the Multimedia Programming Guide, software decoding is supported for everything except HE-AAC since OS 3.0. Also note that software MP3 decoding can use a significant amount of CPU time.

Alternatively, explicitly convert the audio using AudioConverter or (possibly) AudioUnit with kAudioUnitSubType_AUConverter. If you do this, it might be worthwhile decompressing everything once and keeping it in memory to minimize overhead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I replaced AudioFileReadBytes() by AudioFileReadPacketData(). I updated the question with my new code. The problem persists though, all I get is noise.

Comment: What did you decide to go with, out of interest?

Comment: I'm using AVAudioPlayer, it fits my needs quite well. Still don't know how I could miss it. Thanks again for your great answer.